# Problem with the url encoding?

Tags: objective-c

here I am using the URL encoding by using the methos as:

Iam passing the url as parameter to this method

```
-(NSData *)addActon:(CustomerDetails*)aCustomerDetails
{
NSString* addCustomerString=@"";
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Customer>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Name>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerName length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerName];

}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Name>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<PaymentsDue>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerPaymentsDue length]!=0)
{
    if([aCustomerDetails.customerPaymentsDue isEqualToString:@"Due On Receipt"])
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *str1=[aCustomerDetails.customerPaymentsDue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Net" withString:@""];
        str1=[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:str1];

    }

}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</PaymentsDue>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CurrencyCode>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerCurrencyCode length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerCurrencyCode];

}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CurrencyCode>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<BillingAddress>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerBillingAddress length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerBillingAddress];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</BillingAddress>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<BillingCity>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerBillingCity length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerBillingCity];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</BillingCity>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<BillingState>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerBillingState length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerBillingState];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</BillingState>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<BillingZip>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerBillingZip length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerBillingZip];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</BillingZip>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<BillingCountry>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerBillingCountry length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerBillingCountry];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</BillingCountry>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<BillingFax>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerBillingFax length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerBillingFax];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</BillingFax>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<ShippingAddress>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerShippingAddress length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerShippingAddress];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</ShippingAddress>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<ShippingCity>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerShippingCity length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerShippingCity];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</ShippingCity>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<ShippingState>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerShippingState length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerShippingState];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</ShippingState>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<ShippingZip>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerShippingZip length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString: aCustomerDetails.customerShippingZip];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</ShippingZip>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<ShippingCountry>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerShippingCountry length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerShippingCountry];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</ShippingCountry>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<ShippingFax>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customerShippingFax length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customerShippingFax];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</ShippingFax>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Contacts>"];
printf("\n isnde add action for add customer contacts list count :%d",[aCustomerDetails.contactList count]);

for(int i=0;i<[aCustomerDetails.contactList count];i++)
{
    Contacts* object=[aCustomerDetails.contactList objectAtIndex:i];
    printf("\n insde add customers conatct id :%s",[object.customerContactId UTF8String]);
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Contact>"];

    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Salutation>"];
    if([object.customerSalutation length]!=0)
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:object.customerSalutation];
    }
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Salutation>"];
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<FirstName>"];
    if([object.customerFirstName length]!=0)
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:object.customerFirstName];
    }
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</FirstName>"];
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<LastName>"];
    if([object.customerLastName length]!=0)
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:object.customerLastName];
    }
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</LastName>"];
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<EMail>"];
    if([object.customerEmail length]!=0)
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:object.customerEmail];
    }
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</EMail>"];
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Phone>"];
    if([object.customerPhone length]!=0)
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:object.customerPhone];
    }
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Phone>"];
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Mobile>"];
    if([object.customerMobile length]!=0)
    {
        addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:object.customerMobile];
    }
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Mobile>"];

    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Contact>"];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Contacts>"];

addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFields>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFieldLabel1>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customFieldLabel1 length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customFieldLabel1];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFieldLabel1>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFieldValue1>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customFieldValue1 length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customFieldValue1];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFieldValue1>"];

addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFieldLabel2>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customFieldLabel2 length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customFieldLabel2];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFieldLabel2>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFieldValue2>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customFieldValue2 length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customFieldValue2];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFieldValue2>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFieldLabel3>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customFieldLabel3 length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customFieldLabel3];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFieldLabel3>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<CustomFieldValue3>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.customFieldValue3 length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.customFieldValue3];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFieldValue3>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</CustomFields>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"<Notes>"];
if([aCustomerDetails.notes length]!=0)
{
    addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:aCustomerDetails.notes];
}
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Notes>"];
addCustomerString=[addCustomerString stringByAppendingString:@"</Customer>"];

printf("\n ================addCustomerString %s",[addCustomerString UTF8String]);
ZohoAppDelegate *appDelegate =  (ZohoAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString* stringB = [self _encodeString:addCustomerString];
NSString* curl = @"https://invoice.zoho.com/api/customers/create?ticket=";
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.ticket];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&apikey=bfc9c6dde7c889a19f8deea9d75345cd&XMLString="];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:stringB];
curl = [curl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:curl];

NSData *returnData;

[self updateStatus];
if (internetConnectionStatus == NotReachable) 
{
    reachbleAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Zoho Invoice"
                                               message:@"No Network Available. \n This Application requires network connectivity. "
                                              delegate:self 
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                     otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [reachbleAlert show];   
    [reachbleAlert release];

}
else 
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL 
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                          timeoutInterval:10];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    printf("\n return string:%s",[returnString UTF8String]);
}



return returnData;
```

}

```
 - (NSString *)_encodeString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, 
                 (CFStringRef)string, 
                 NULL, 
                 (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=$+{}<>,",
                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

but I am passing the parameter as customer name: 1234~!@#$%^&*(((((())_+|"?:><.,; 
and the method is encoding the customer along with the url and Im getting the error message as url is not well formed.

can anyone suggest how to get out of this....

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.
Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Can we see the code calling this function and the data as I don't understand what you mean by passing the parameter as customer name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should not be adding the customerData to your URL. The request is a Http POST request and the data that is posted is sent by the setHTTPBody: method see [NSMutableURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Thus you don't need to put it in the same string as the URL. The URL is he address of the request and not its data

Comment: StingB is the customer data which Im adding to the URL.